# CMD Output to a logfile.txt

Tags: file, batch-file, logging, cmd, copy

Script:

```
pushd "\\server1\share\Data\"
for %%p in (*.pdf) do if /i ".pdf"=="%%~xp" for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%n in ("%%~np") do ( 
    copy "%%~fp" ""\\server2share\data\%%~n\%%~nxp" dir >> \\server\share\logfile.txt

)
```

I want to log the output everytime this command runs. The script copies pdf's based on name. But when i run the script. No log file is created.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

EDITED to adapt to comments

```
pushd "\\server1\share\Data\"
set "logFile=\\server\share\logfile.txt"
for %%p in (*.pdf) do if /i ".pdf"=="%%~xp" for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%n in ("%%~np") do ( 
    if not exist ""\\server2share\data\%%~n\" (
        >>"%logFile%" echo SKIPPED : "%%~nxp"
    ) else (
        copy "%%~fp" "\\server2share\data\%%~n\%%~nxp" 
        if errorlevel 1 (
            >>"%logFile%" echo FAILED  : "%%~nxp"
        ) else (
            >>"%logFile%" echo COPIED  : "%%~nxp"
        )
    )
)
popd
```

You have a dir command in a strange place, changed to echo. And, i'm not sure all the paths are right.

Comment: this comment adds a log when the file did coppied ? And when it doesnt exist it doesnt log ? (I just want to know, nothing more )

Comment: Every **PUSHD** should have its corresponding **POPD**. Otherwise, if you run your script repeatedly, you will encounter memory leaks and/or exhaustion of disk drive letters.

Comment: Why ? It's only using one directory.

Comment: @user3360442, It adds a line for each file that is processed by the `for` command. If you need to ensure the file is copied, then add a check for errorlevel. If it doesn't exist? What should be copied if something does not exist? The `for` command iterates over the existing pdf files.

Comment: Well, there are some cases a file should not be copied if the directory target doesnt exist. So the script doesnt copy a thing. The script works. But i only want a log file to see what the script actually did. So what i see in the cmd view, and export that into a txt

Answer (score 0):

```
pushd "\\server1\share\Data\"
for %%p in (*.pdf) do if /i ".pdf"=="%%~xp" for /f "tokens=1 delims=_" %%n in ("%%~np") do ( 
  md "\\server2share\data\%%~n" 2>nul
  copy "%%~fp" "\\server2share\data\%%~n\%%~nxp" 
  dir >> \\server\share\logfile.txt

)
```

(untested)

I'm assuming the way your scrip is arranged from your original post.

If you want to execute a sequence of separate commands, they need to be separated by <kbd>&</kbd> or be on separate lines.

You had an extra <kbd>"</kbd> in your `copy` command

Inserted a `md` command with error-message-suppression to ensure the destination directory exists.

Comment: Yes - `md` and `mkdir` are synonyms.

Comment: The folders that are already in the directory are programmed, so no need to add.. I only want a check if the file is copied (or not) a logfile..

Comment: So - omit the `md` line. Leaving it there will do no harm, the `2>nul` part suppresses any error messages about trying to make an existing directory. And it's a safety measure - in case the destination directory doesn't exist for some reason...

Comment: it did created some directory's. Not really a problem, i can delete them afterwise. But it's not what im looking for

Answer (score 0):

This will create a log of what is shown on the cmd screen while it is running, but you will not see any output on the screen.   You can use a `tee` filter if you also need to see the screen output.

```
mybatch.bat>file.log
```